How to select all the input elements except for the ones within a specific element
I want to select all the inputs in a form except those within a specific element.
Consider the following sample HTML:
<form id="myForm">
    <input />
    <input />

    <div class="excluded">
        <input />
        <input />
    </div>
</form>

The following doesn't work:
const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
const inputs = myForm.querySelectors(":not(.excluded) input");

I worked around it by setting special class names for those ones by doing this:
const exInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".excluded input");
exInputs.forEach(input => input.classList.add("excluded"));

Now, somewhere else, I could do this:
const inputs = myForm.querySelectorAll("input:not(.excluded)");

But, there must be a more straightforward method of excluding nested elements, right?!

Ok, I figured it out! It's basically the same :not() exclusion, but with a slight modification. So, Instead of:
const input = myForm.querySelectorAll("input:not(.excluded input)")

And that's it, turns out!
According to MDN, and I quote:

The :not() CSS pseudo-class represents elements that do not match a list of selectors. Since it prevents specific items from being selected, it is known as the negation pseudo-class.

So, basically, whatever that goes in :not() gets compared to the attached element itself. Now, if that element matches the selectors within :not() it's gets negated; in other words, excluded.

Can you elaborate on this?

@ChukwujiobiCanon Thank you for asking! I included some more details.

You can also exclude the input elements by placing them outside the form element/not as child elements to the form. And then include them in the form, using the form attribute on the input elements outside the form.


let form = document.forms.myForm;

// All child form fields to the form
console.log([...form.querySelectorAll('input')].map(elm => elm.name));

// All form fiels in the form
console.log([...form.elements].map(elm => elm.name));
<form id="myForm">
  <input name="input01" />
  <input name="input02" />
</form>
<div class="excluded">
  <input name="input03" form="myForm" />
  <input name="input04" form="myForm" />
</div>



And an aside. Sometimes the <fieldset> elements is also useful as a way to divide up form fields.


let form = document.forms.myForm;

// All form fields from the included fieldset
console.log([...form.included.elements].map(elm => elm.name));

// All form fields from the excluded fieldset
console.log([...form.excluded.elements].map(elm => elm.name));

// All form controls from the form
console.log([...form.elements].map(elm => elm.name));
<form id="myForm">
  <fieldset name="included">
    <input name="input01" />
    <input name="input02" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="excluded">
    <input name="input03" />
    <input name="input04" />
  </fieldset>
</form>



